# Searching for the Minimum Value in a list of AutoFiltered values produces Type Mismatch Error

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling, autofilter

I have filtered my data ("[h]:mm:ss;@") to give times between 0 and 15 minutes and then produce the minimum value in this range. If there are no values between 0 and 15 minutes I would like it to produce a blank and move on in the loop. However, when there are no values in the filtered list it produces a Type Mismatch Error. I tried to handle the error to no avail. What am I doing wrong?

```
Columns("G:G").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$G:$G").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">0:00:00", _
    Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<0:15:00"

MinValue = Application.Min(searchRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
MinRow = Application.Match(MinValue, searchRange, 0)
On Error GoTo ContinueProcess:


Cells(j, 8).Value = MinRow
Cells(j, 9).Value = Cells(MinRow, 3)
Cells(j, 10).Value = Cells(MinRow, 4)
Cells(j, 11).Value = Cells(MinRow, 6)

ContinueProcess:
    Resume Next
ActiveSheet.Range("$G:$G").AutoFilter Field:=1


Next j
```

Comment: Rather than **Application.Min** why not use **Application.Subtotal**

Answer (score 0):

Use `Application.SubTotal` rather than `Min`, Either the *5* or the *15* *function* parameter will give you a non-error on the filtered data. This will result in *zero* when there are no numbers to check and that is easily compensated for to change to blank either with number formatting or an `IF` check. see [SUBTOTAL function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/subtotal-function-HP010062463.aspx) for more on the *function* parameter's options.